# php/sql - Efficient Union?

Tags: php, mysql

[image]Im trying to make this query more efficient, basically what this does is it selects multiple user accounts from different tables, into a single query. I know that join is more efficient, but im having a hard time understanding them for some reason. Is there any other efficient way to make this code shorter? Or do i need to make an adjustment to my tables?

```
select id_number, password from students
  where
  id_number = '$username' AND password = '$password'
  union 
  select id_number, password from faculty 
  where
  id_number = '$username' AND password = '$password'
  union 
  select id_number, password from registrar 
  where
  id_number = '$username' AND password = '$password'
```

Comment: Show your database schema, and we might be able to give you more information.

Comment: just added the schema.

Answer (score 1):

`join` is not the same, and not necessarily more efficient than `union`. For the query that you're showing, `union`, or rather `union all` seems to be the best solution.

You may want to use `union all` to get all the record that match. `union` will deduplicate them as if you did `select distinct`.

But in general, this model is wrong. In this scenario, you could have a student named bob, and a registrar named bob, and if both would happend to have chosen the same password, you'd get both of them. This way you risk that students can hack into accounts of others (or vice versa).

A better model would be to have a single set of accounts in which you manage the account name and password **hash** (not password). You can link such an account either to a student, or a registrar, or a faculty (or multiple, if your application would allow tying multiple roles to a single user name).

Modeling this way would prevent having two different entities with the same login name, and as such would also prevent the accidental bad consequences of having colliding user names.